# Microsoft cognitive-services audiooutputconfig device_name

Tags: azure, azure-speech

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-cognitiveservices-speech/azure.cognitiveservices.speech.audio.audiooutputconfig?view=azure-python

how to specify a device_name I have tried everything from deviceUID,deviceName nothing seems to work

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

**Device_name** Specifies the id of the audio device to use. Here is a sample [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z3o-Dyg9KNE) for Audio device IDs on Windows for desktop applications, Audio device IDs on UWP. Refer this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/how-to-select-audio-input-devices) for more information

For more information about using the Speech-to-text and Text-to-speech APIs, see this [link](https://microsoftlearning.github.io/AI-102-AIEngineer/Instructions/07-speech.html)